# How to find files in folders?

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu

Without using command line. Let's say I open a folder where I have many sub-folders with different songs and I want to find some song that contain some word in the title. Is it possible?

With command line I'd do it with grep

Comment: From the command line, use locate or the command find.

Comment: On Xubuntu you can use catfish https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXyc6TyVWOs in the filemanager thunar just right click in the folder then click "Find in the folder".

Answer (score 3):

Yes ctrl+F it will find files not only in current directory but sub-directories also

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive search on Nautilus using <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>.

[image: nautilus recurseive search screenshot]